# SQL Server: Pivot

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot-table

Please help me with this. I have the data as this:

```
 ID          Name          TotalCost   IsCorporate        
 ----   ----------------  ----------   -----------
 1      Wash, Dry & Fold      175.00       1
 2      Hand Wash and Fold    275.00       0
 3      Pressing Only         25.00        0
 4      Hand Wash and Fold    205.00       1
 5      Pressing Only         100.00       0
```

If `IsCorporate = 0` then the `Total Cost` will align to the `Corporate` column like this:

```
 ID   Wash, Dry & Fold Hand Wash and Fold Pressing Only    Corporate
 ---- ---------------- -----------------  -------------- -----------
 1         175.00    
 2                                                          275.00
 3                                                          25.00                                                  
 4                        205.00                   
 5                                                         100.00
```

This is my stored procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportSales] 
AS
BEGIN   
    SELECT 
        IDJO, ISCORP, ST.[Wash, Dry & Fold], ST.[Pressing Only], 
        ST.[Dry Clean], ST.[Hand Wash and Fold], ST.[Wash, Dry & Press], 
        ST.[Stain Removal], ST.[Hand Wash and Press], CORPORATE
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             JO.Id AS IDJO, CI.Active AS ISCORP, ST.Name, 
             ISNULL(JO.TotalCost, 0) AS TC
         FROM  
             JobOrders JO 
         INNER JOIN
             ClientInformations CI ON JO.ClientId = CI.Id 
         INNER JOIN
             JobOrderDetails JOD ON JO.Id = JOD.JOrderId 
         INNER JOIN
             ServiceTypes ST ON JOD.ServiceId = ST.Id 
         INNER JOIN
             Payments P ON JO.Id = P.JobOrderId 
         INNER JOIN
             PaymentStatus PS ON JO.PaymentStatusId = PS.Id 
         INNER JOIN
             Status S ON JO.StatusId = s.Id) AS J 
    PIVOT 
        (SUM(TC) for Name IN  ([Wash, Dry & Fold], [Pressing Only], [Dry
Clean],  [Hand Wash and Fold], [Wash, Dry & Press], [Stain Removal],
[Hand Wash and Press], [Corporate])  ) AS ST
END
```

Comment: I don't see how this is really a dynamic pivot, but you would have a much easier time using conditional aggregation over a PIVOT IMO. e.g. `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Wash, Dry & Fold' AND isCorporate = 1 THEN TC END), SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Pressing Only'...` etc with an additional `SUM(CASE WHEN isCorporate = 0 THEN TC END)`

Answer (score 0):

Use **dynamic column collection to select PIVOT Data**, because it gives you any new column value added in table, suppose after 2-3 days if **new Name** say for XYZ added in your table **even that it show your new column in PIVOT** result:

```
CREATE TABLE ReportSales
 (
    ID INT,
    Name  VARCHAR(50),
    TotalCost DECIMAL(10,2),
    IsCorporate BIT
 )  

 INSERT INTO ReportSales VALUES(1,'Wash, Dry & Fold',175.00,1)
 ,(2,'Hand Wash and Fold',275.00,0)
 ,(3,'Pressing Only',25.00,0)
 ,(4,'Hand Wash and Fold',205.00,1)
 ,(5,'Pressing Only',100.00,0)  

DECLARE @Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@Query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Name = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
            FROM ReportSales c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @Query =    
'IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#tblRS'') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tblRS

SELECT
    ID,
    RS.Name,
    TotalCost,
    ISCorporate,
    CASE RS.IsCorporate WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE RS.TotalCost END AS Corporate
INTO #tblRS
FROM ReportSales RS

SELECT ID, ' + @Name + ',Corporate from 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE ISCorporate WHEN 1 THEN TotalCost ELSE 0 END AS NewTotalCost 
    FROM #tblRS
) x
pivot 
(
    SUM(TotalCost)
    FOR Name in (' + @Name + ')
) p '

PRINT(@query)
EXECUTE(@query)
```

**@Name :** It will give you your column list on which you wants to apply SUM